# Javascript button delete and edit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can add a user just fine, but when I try to delete or edit someone my button doesn't work. I tried to put an alert to see what's wrong but I can't find anything.

As you can see it creates the button delete and edit when you add someone to the table.

Here's my js code:

```
var nextId = 1;
var activeId = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#addBtn").on("click", function() {
        var name = $("#txtNome").val();
        if (name.trim().length < 3 || $("#txtIdade").val() == "") {
            alert("Dados Incorretos, Por favor, digite o seu nome e idade.");
            $("#txtNome").focus();
            return false;
        } else {
            addt();
            formClear();
        }
    });
    $("#btnDelete").on("click", function(delete_button) {
        $(delete_button).parents("tr").remove();
    });
    $("#btnEdit").click(function() {
        var row = $(edit_button).parents("tr");
        var cols = row.children("td");
        activeId = $($(cols[2]).children("button")[0]).data("id");
        $("#txtNome").val($(cols[0]).text());
        $("#txtIdade").val($(cols[1]).text());
        $("#edt").css("display", "inline-block");
        $("#addBtn").prop("disabled", true);
    })
    function addt() {
        if ($("#tblUser tbody").length == 0) {
            $("#tblUser").append("<tbody></tbody>");
        }
        $("#tblUser tbody").append(addUserToTable(nextId));
        nextId += 1;
    }
    function addUserToTable(id) {
        var row =
            "<tr>" +
            "<td>" + $("#txtNome").val() + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + $("#txtIdade").val() + "</td>" +
            "<td>" +
            "<button type='button' style='margin-right:20px;' " + "id='btnEdit' " + "class='btn btn-default'" + "data-id='" + nextId + "'>" + "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span>" +
            "</button>" +

            "<button type='button' " + "id='btnDelete'" + "class='btn btn-default'" + "data-id='" + nextId + "'>" + "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span>" +
            "</button>" +
            "</td>" +
            "</tr>"
        return row;
        nextId += 1;
    }
    function formClear() {
        $("#txtNome").val("");
        $("#txtIdade").val("");
    }
    function attTable(id) {
        var row = $("#tblUser button[data-id='" + id + "']").parents("tr")[0];
        $(row).after(addUserToTable());
        $(row).remove();
        formClear();
        $("#edt").css("display", "none");
    }
});
```

Comment: What errors do you get in your browser's console? We'll also need a [mcve] in your question.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The click functions are called before the elements are added to the table. Try setting the event on the button itself <button onclick="function"></button>

Comment: Could you please accept the answer if answer solve your problem ?

Comment: ill try when i get home tonight

Answer (score 0):

As you are adding String content(in form of HTML) to a table, so these are the new content for document, and Jquery has bind all event at time of page load,

So when you add dynamic content to table, you explicitly need to bind the events to DOM elements (in your case edit and delete button)

Please try following code,

```
<script>
var nextId = 1;
var activeId = 0;

$(document).ready(function(){


    $("#addBtn").on("click",function(){
        var name = $("#txtNome").val();
        if (name.trim().length < 3 || $("#txtIdade").val() == "") {
            alert("Dados Incorretos, Por favor, digite o seu nome e idade.");
            $("#txtNome").focus();
            return false;
        } else {
            addt();
            formClear();
        }
    });


    $("#btnDelete").on("click",deletebutton);


    function deletebutton(){
        $(this).parents("tr").remove();
    }

    $("#btnEdit").click(editButton);

    function editButton(){

        var row = $(this).parents("tr");
        var cols = row.children("td");

        activeId = $($(cols[2]).children("button")[0]).data("id");

        $("#txtNome").val($(cols[0]).text());
        $("#txtIdade").val($(cols[1]).text());

        $("#edt").css("display", "inline-block");
        $("#addBtn").prop("disabled" , true);


    }
    function addt(){
        if ($("#tblUser tbody").length == 0) {
            $("#tblUser").append("<tbody></tbody>");
        }
        var btn = $(addUserToTable(nextId));
        $(btn).find("#btnEdit").bind('click', editButton);
        $(btn).find("#btnDelete").bind('click', deletebutton);
        $("#tblUser tbody").append($(btn));
        nextId += 1;
    }

    function addUserToTable(id) {

        var row =
        "<tr>" +
        "<td>" + $("#txtNome").val() + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + $("#txtIdade").val() + "</td>" +
        "<td>" +
        "<button type='button' style='margin-right:20px;' " +       "id='btnEdit' " + "class='btn btn-default'" + "data-id='" + nextId + "'>" + "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span>" +
              "Edit </button>" +

              "<button type='button' " + "id='btnDelete'" + "class='btn btn-default'" + "data-id='" + nextId + "'>" + "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span>" +
              "Delete</button>" +
              "</td>" +

              "</tr>"

          return row;


          nextId += 1;

      }

      function formClear() {
          $("#txtNome").val("");
          $("#txtIdade").val("");
      }


      function attTable(id) {
        var row = $("#tblUser button[data-id='" + id + "']").parents("tr")[0];


          $(row).after(addUserToTable());

          $(row).remove();

          formClear();

          $("#edt").css("display", "none");
      }


}); 
</script>
```

I hope this will solve your problem

I have tried with following HTML content

```
<table id="tblUser"></table>

<input type="button" id="addBtn" value="addBtn"/><br/>
<input type="button" id="btnDelete" value="btnDelete"/><br/>
<input type="button" id="btnEdit" value="btnEdit"/><br/>
txtNome: <input type="text" id="txtNome" value="Name 1" /><br/>
txtIdade: <input type="text" id="txtIdade" value="Name 2"/><br/>
```